# I am sending different-different PDF to different mail from excel file using Java mail API, getting corrupted on receivers mail?

Tags: java, email, pdf, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

> I am new user of java mail API. I am trying to send different-
>   different PDF to different Email Id . Here email-id and file path is
>   taken from a excel file using ArrayList that is returned by another
>   class. But the attached file is getting corrupted on receivers mail. I
>   have checked all the questions and answers on stack over flow related
>   to this problem, but anything is not working. Please help me. I have
>   given program that i have written . Please help me.

```
package emailsending;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Email {

    String username;
    String password;
    String excelFileName;
    String result = null;
    String filename, status;
    ArrayList email;

    byte[] buf = {};
    ArrayList list_filename;
    public Email(String username, String password, String excelFileName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.excelFileName = excelFileName;
        excelReading er = new excelReading(excelFileName);
        ArrayList li = er.email_file();
        email = (ArrayList) li.get(0);
        list_filename = (ArrayList) li.get(1);
    }

    public Email() {

    }

    public String sendToAll() {
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.SocketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.SocketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.ssLSocketFactory");
            System.err.println("Properties set----");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(false);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setSubject("Client Receipt");
            //1. First body part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText("This is your receipt");

            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            MimeBodyPart fileBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            for (int i = 0; i < email.size(); i++) {
                status = "Sending first mail:-" + email.get(i);
                System.err.println(status);
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(((String) email.get(i)).trim()));
                filename = ((String) list_filename.get(i)).trim();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                DataHandler lDataHandler = new DataHandler(source);

                fileBodyPart.setDataHandler(lDataHandler);
                fileBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

                multipart.addBodyPart(fileBodyPart);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                message.setContent(multipart);

                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
                transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                result = "Sucessfully sent Email";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = "Unable to send Email" + ex.getMessage();
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail tries to choose the correct encoding for an attachment based on the content of the attachment.  In rare cases some files, such as pdf files, will look like they're plain text files but will actually contain binary data, causing JavaMail to choose the wrong encoding.  Try using the [MimeBodyPart method that allows you to specify the encoding](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), and use "base64" encoding.  If that doesn't solve the problem, we'll need a lot more details about exactly how the received file is "corrupted".

Comment: I have already tried your suggestion  but it's still not working . Header that i have already tried:                
               **fileBodyPart.setDataHandler(lDataHandler); 
                fileBodyPart.setFileName(lDataHandler.getName());
                fileBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
                fileBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
                
                multipart.addBodyPart(fileBodyPart);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);**

Comment: Did you add all those headers, or did you do what I suggested?  If it's still not working, I need more details.